# Changed font to ttf for the whole document, how to change back for a single word?

Tags: fonts, truetype

I've changed the font of my document to a ttf one (by switching to lualatex and using the `\setmainfont{}` keyword). Everything is fine with it.

However, there are some senteces/words in the document, for which I would still use the default Latex font.

How can I switch back to the default latex fonts, only for some parts of them?

Comment: `\newfontfamily\myfont{<font name here>}`?

Comment: @JairoAdelRio Thanks. Question is then only, what is the name of the default font.

Comment: \fontfamily {lmr}\selectfont   should work too

Comment: Latin Modern Roman

Comment: To limit the scope of the change, place it in grouping braces, such as `old blah {\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont new blah} old blah`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your answer, it sounds like what you really wanted was to switch to the default font, and you have an [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  The best way to to that is to switch to the OpenType font Latin Modern Roman (or New Computer Modern, or CMU Serif, all of which are OpenType clones of Computer Modern).  These support all the features of the legacy font, and then some.

You can do this by declaring it as a font family:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}[Scale=1.0]
\newfontfamily\LMR{Latin Modern Roman}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  Ligatures={Common,TeX}]

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlm}{\LMR}

\begin{document}
Adventor and \textlm{Latin Modern Roman}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

The command `\fontspec{Latin Modern Roman}` would also work, but I don’t recommend it.

To answer the question you literally asked, switching to a Type 1 font in the middle of a document means selecting a NFSS font family and a font encoding.  Nearly all the text fonts you’d want to use have been converted to a more modern format, so it’s more likely you would need to do this with a symbol font, but here I give an contrived example that switches to the T1-encoded version of TeX Gyre Adventor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\DeclareTextFontCommand\textag{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\textag{Adventor} and Latin Modern Roman.
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

If for some reason you want to switch between the legacy and modern encodings of the same font, you can load the font with the `NFSSFamily=` option, and then switch between Unicode and legacy encodings with `\fontencoding`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[NFSSFamily=lmr]

\begin{document}
Latin Modern Roman {\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont in Cork encoding.}
\end{document}
```

In this example, you can’t see any difference, but dumping the list of fonts in the documents with `pdffonts` gives you,

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
QCCKES+LMRoman10-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
XKHIOF+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
```

This shows that it did switch between the modern font and the legacy Type 1 font.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comment-answers, finally I made it with

```
\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont{...content...}
```

It works because `lmr` (Latin Modern Roman) is the default Latex font, and this markup sets this for `...content...`.